# Where can one download Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation without using NuGet

Tags: nuget, unobtrusive-validation

I'd like to download the latest version of Microsoft jQuery Unobtrusive Validation, however I don't like using NuGet since it is not possible for me to tell it where to install the packages within my project structure.

Does Microsoft host these files somewhere that I can access them directly?

Comment: For future reference, you can use the [`NuGet.Downloader`](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2011/03/10/nuget-downloader-package-download-a-local-nuget-repository-using-nuget.aspx) to only download a package (not install) then you can include packages in your project as you see fit. Additionally, most of the projects on NuGet have a "Project" link on the Nuget.org site which you cna follow (and most of _those_ link to source repositories which you can grab the library itself without nuget).

Answer (score 38):

The files for ASP.NET MVC 5.2 aren't (yet?) on the page I mention below, but the links are valid:

- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
- http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

[Copied from [Maxime's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26181069/173497) to this question.]

I found a page – [Microsoft Ajax Content Delivery Network - ASP.NET Ajax Library](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx) – that lists several versions of the files for this that you can download.

Here are the ones I found via searching that page for "unobtrusive":

> ASP.NET MVC 5.1
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.1/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.1/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>
> ASP.NET MVC 5.0
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>
> ASP.NET MVC 4.0
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/4.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>
> ASP.NET MVC 3.0
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>   http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/3.0/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>
> ...

Comment: Do we have any information other then the CDN on what these files are used for? Example documentation.

Comment: @Jessycormier, the *jquery.validate.unobtrusive* files effectively convert (MVC) server-side validation attributes into jQuery Validation state (i.e. it calls jQuery Validation functions to map MVC validation). The *jquery.unobtrusive-ajax* provides 'automatic' AJAX features for MVC; [here's a blog post that covers it](http://chsakell.com/2013/05/12/mvc-unobtrusive-ajax/).

Answer (score 11):

Here are the links :

> **jQuery Unobtrusive for ASP.NET MVC 5.2.3**
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.3/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>
> **jQuery Unobtrusive for ASP.NET MVC 5.2.2**
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js
>
> **jQuery Unobtrusive for ASP.NET MVC 5.2**
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js
>
> http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/mvc/5.2/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js

And by using these files, you will also need to include jquery.validate(.min).js.  The latest files can be found :

> **jQuery Validate**
>
> http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn#jQuery_Validation_Releases_on_the_CDN_3
>   or 
>   http://jqueryvalidation.org/

You can browse the **Microsoft Ajax CDN** for all needed librairies: http://www.asp.net/ajax/cdn

Answer (score 0):

It's available/hosted by google here [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/tfsstatus/source/browse/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation.2.0.20505.0/?r=a95786c3fc70eba41949a29ee17107c3d1c766c5)

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to have the latest version (2.0.30116.0)