# mvc dropdownlst initial value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list in MVC

Model:

```
[Required]  
[Display(Name = "State of Residency:")]  
public string StateCode { get; set; }
```

My View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("StateCode", "Select")
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StateCode)
```

The drop down list works fine but how to make the validator validate the select. So it say please select a value in Select is there.

Comment: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4729440/validate-a-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc) very nice example

Comment: Thank you, but I'm knew to mvc I'm using two tables with FK for StateCode, The problem is that the validator assume that Select is an imput.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Example for ASP.NET MVC 5 web application:

In your case I would make like so:

1) Enable validation in web.config

```
<appSettings>    
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

2) add proper jQuery files

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script> <!--v1.13.0-->
 <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script> <!-- For ASP.NET MVC 5.0 -->
```

3) StateCode.cs

```
 public class StateCode
 {
     public int Id { get; set; }
     public int Code { get; set; }
 }
```

4) MyModel.cs

```
 public class MyModel
 {
     [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select")]
     public int IdSelected { get; set; }

     [Display(Name = "State of Residency:")]
     public IEnumerable<StateCode> StateCodes { get; set; }
 }
```

5) Action

```
 [HttpGet]
 public virtual ActionResult Index()
 {
      var model = new MyModel
      {
          StateCodes = new List<StateCode>
          {
              new StateCode{Id=1, Code=22333}, 
              new StateCode{Id=2, Code=44433},  
              new StateCode{Id=3, Code=55533},  
          }
      };
      return View(model);
  }
```

6) View

```
  @model MyModel

  @using (Html.BeginForm())
  {
     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IdSelected, new SelectList(Model.StateCodes, "Id", "Code"), "Please Select")
     @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IdSelected)

     <input type="submit" value="OK" />
  }
```

btw. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15974230/where-can-one-download-microsoft-jquery-unobtrusive-validation-without-using-nug) very good list of jQuery files for ASP.NET MVC unobtrusive validation.

Comment: After I tried this:  @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.StateCode, new SelectList(Model.State, "StateCode", "StateName"), "Pleasesssssss")   I'm getting The best overloaded method match for "System.Web.Mvc.Selectlist.Selectlist(System.Colections.IEnumerable, string, string)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `x.StateCode` should be `int` and `Model.State` should be `IEnumerable<T>` - do you have the same?
btw. it would be better if you will rename `Model.State` to `Model.States` as it's list

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion I agree it should be states. The solution above worked for me